# [play framework]Leverage browser caching

Tags: caching, playframework, browser-cache

I ran a test run for speed test of my page. It said "Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.".

My Page using Play Framework. Came across a lot of answers regarding .htaccess file but it is not supported in Play Framework. How to cache the static files on browser level?

Comment: Are you running Play in production mode? If so the browser should cache the assets already...

Comment: Yes. I am running it on production mode. Still google page insight says the statement. @Salem

Answer (score 1):

When using Play in production mode, it already sets the `ETag` header, so whenever a browser requests a file matching that eTag, play just returns `304 Not Modified`. This will save you data (the browser will not download the file again if it has the right version), but still requires a request to the server.

If you want to specify a expiracy date, you can use `assets.defaultCache="max-age=3600"` to your `application.conf` (adapt the value for your needs: 3600 is one hour in seconds).

I can't check this right now, but I think Play also sets `Cache-Control: max-age=3600`, so probably the warning you are getting is because this value is too low for the tool you are using to check the caching.

You can also set the expiracy time to individual assets (see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview#Additional-Cache-Control-directive)

Note that you should only specify a high expiracy time to assets that you are sure that don't change a lot...

Comment: Thanks for the help @Salem

Comment: Great, thanks! The setting `assets.defaultCache` works, but only in production mode, so don't test the header when in development mode (`sbt run`).